# Background color not showing without position:absolute

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm writing down a website using HTML and CSS3 and I have encountered some problems putting div's into each other and using the absolute position. When I add the position:absolute, I can set the div's background color and manipulate the objects within it, but it's been removed from the DOM, which creates some other difficulties for me (like not knowing how to set a footer). My question is how to make so, that all the elements inside my `#content` div are aligned properly, the height is set automatically and the background-color is the same for all of them?

UPDATE:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdBVk/)

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: I tried, but it appears way differently from my local file, don't know why...

Comment: Updated, this is the way it looks. I want to set the same background behind the test boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a div with `clear` class upper than footer and style `clear: both;`

```
...
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
...
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hQhcv/1/)